# Spider identification (Caribbean)

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

I live in the Caribbean (Puerto Rico) and found this spider in my garage. Is it venomous?

It measures about 8 inches as a whole.

[image: Image of Puerto Rica spider]

Comment: Please provide a more specific location. Country is necessary, but even more specifics (town/city, local habitat that your garage is surrounded by, etc.) are helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a Banana Spider:

> [image]
>
> ... a male Heteropoda venatoria, also called a Banana Spider. The female is a more robust spider with shorter legs. This is the spider that is responsible for the rumors that tarantulas come into the U.S. with bananas because they are often spotted emerging frrom a bunch of bananas in a fruit store in the North. This Giant Crab Spider is usually the culprit. The species is found in all tropical regions, its range extending clear around the world. It is very abundant in all tropical seaport towns, being transported in trading vessels. Its chief food is cockroaches. The female carries her eggs beneath her body. According to this site it is also called the Huntsman Spider.

- https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2003/11/11/banana-spider-from-peurto-rico/